# Input Value not Displaying in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

For some reason my input value won't display in console...

Here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="area"><td class="icon"></td> 
    <td class="title">
       <div>
         User: <input id="inputUser" type="text" style="margin-top: 2px;margin-left:2px"></input> 
         Ammount: <input id="inputAmmount" type="text" style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:2px; padding-right: 0px"></input>
       </div>
      <td><a class="btn" style="margin-top:3px">Submit</a></td>
    </td>        
</tr>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
        console.log("click detected");
        var userID = $('#inputUser').val();
        var ammount = $('#inputAmmount').val();
        console.log(userID);
});
```

The console is successfully outputting "click detected" but for the userID it doesn't display anything.

Comment: You defined a variable `user`, but you're trying to log `userID`...

Comment: console.log(user) maybe .. userId is not there.

Comment: my bad that was an error during copy pasting, it's still not working for me

Comment: Works in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d6rstbe/1/). Are you sure you don't have `inputUser` defined multiple times? And obviously you have typed something into the `#inputUser` input before clicking submit?

Comment: I tried "document.getElementById("#inputUser").value;" and I got an error in the console saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. What I posted above is just part of my code. I feel like the document is not finding the #inputUser

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/1reLtunc/

The only thing I can recommend is that you check that when you create the event listener for the `$('.btn').click` that you are sure that your HTML has been rendered and is not being loaded through ajax.

If it is being loaded through ajax, you will want to rebind the event listener after the ajax call has completed.

Also, make sure you wrap your `$('.btn').click` event listener in a `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ })` or the shorthand equivilent: `$(function() { /* your code here */ })`

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar mistake of this nature several times. When you use document.getElementByID the script already recognizes you are using an ID so you don't need to include the hashtag. document.getElementByID('inputUser').value; will work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!